# Reusing a common PropType shape with props required or not required depending on the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a common proptype (in a lib) that multiple components import and use.

```
ListPropType = PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    creatorId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    ...
});
```

1) For some components, I want to make the name required and for some components, I don't.

2) Also, for some components, I want to add additional props in the shape.

Is there a simple or common way of handling these use cases that doesn't involve duplicating everything but the fields that differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never had to do this, but I suppose you could write a factory method to generate the shape, this way you'd be able to add `isRequired` to fields on the fly.

```
const getShape = (requiredFields, extraFields) => {
  const template = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    creatorId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };
  Object.keys(template).forEach(key => {
    if (requiredFields.includes(key)) {
      template[key] = template[key].isRequired;
    }
  });
  return PropTypes.shape({
    ...template,
    ...extraFields,
  });
}

// Create propType with 'name' required and extra date field
ListPropType = getShape(
  ['name'],
  { date: PropTypes.string }
);
```

You could even abstract this further by taking the starting template as an argument to the `getShape` function.

Comment: Basically what I came up with as well. I pass in a simplified shape, array of required fields, and object of additional fields.